# ip change from dynamic to static and back

Tags: shell-script

I am building a script to pwn networks.
It is supposed to grab the router ip and set that as the machine's static ip (which it does just fine)
when hitting q, it is supposed to exit (and it does) after setting the ip back to a dynamic IP (and it doesn't) to fix the purposely made ip conflict with the router. my raspberry pi is currently pwning a poor little router I isolated from the rest of my home network... after I stop the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=$(ip route show | grep -i 'default via'| awk '{print $3 }')
echo "Press Spacebar to exit. I AM NETPAWN!!! I SHALL KILL YOUR NETWORK!!!!!!" Router ip: “$ip

read input 
if [[ $input = " " ]] || [[ $input = " " ]] 
    then
echo “iface eth0 inet dhcp” >>/etc/network/interfaces
ifconfig eth0 up
exit 1 
else 
    ifconfig eth0 $ip

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the eth0 interface down? If I recall well you need to bring interface down to change its status from down to up.

So try adding `ifconfig eth0 down` or before doing `echo "iface eth0 inet dhcp” >>/etc/network/interfaces` and running `ifconfig eth0 up`

Also ifconfig is getting deprecated you should use ip command instead.

Comment: thank you. I am just starting to get into actually shell scripting. I use Linux quite a bit before tho